# Django: Populating data into a model based on an identifier

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, freebase

In my Django project, let's say I have the following model:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    freebase_id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    latitude = models.DecimalField()
    longitude = models.DecimalField()
    area = models.IntegerField()
```

(I've omitted the required parameters for DecimalField for simplicity).

The user could enter all the fields manually, but I want to make life easier by letting the user enter some kind of ID in the admin area, like a Freebase ID (such as [/en/manchester_united_kingdom](http://www.freebase.com/edit/topic/en/manchester_united_kingdom)), so that we can then use the API to fetch things like `latitude`, `longitude` and `area`.

Long story short, I want to let users provide some ID which can then be used to derive other data inside the model. In an ideal world, the derived fields should be initially hidden in the admin system, but then made visible once populated so that they can be edited.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am doing something similar in my `UserProfile` model.  I have a zip code field that, if it gets filled in by the user, is used to do a geo lookup to get city/state and lat/lng and store them in their respective fields in the model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    ...
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    city_state = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=9, blank=True, null=True)
    lng = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=9, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.zip:
            (city_state, lat, lng) = get_lat_lng(self.zip)
            if city_state and lat and lng:
                self.city_state = city_state
                self.lat = lat
                self.lng = lng

        super(UserProfile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('zip',)
```

Note that the derived form's `zip` field is the only one visible to the user.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a good solution. I guess if you wanted to then display the lat and lng fields for editing later, then you could put conditional statements into the Meta class around "fields ="?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Also, you can pass the model to the template separately and just display any field data as "read-only."  For example, next to the editable `zip` field, I display the `city_state` string (once calculated), so that every time the zip is updated, the user can verify their city/state.

Answer (score 0):

If you override the save() method of your object you can set your lat-long in that. Not sure now to hide fields in that way though. There's new stuff in the latest Django for read-only fields, and if you can do that magically via a custom admin manager you might have a way in...